# How to dynamically created "compiled" React components without babel on the fly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

If I have a nested object of nodes something like (ignore the syntax):

```
const el = {
  node: {
    name: 'Svg',
    attrs: { height: "40", width: "40", viewBox: "0 0 22 22" },
    children: [
      {
        node: {
          name: 'G',
          attrs: null,
          children: [
            {
              node: {
                name: 'Path',
                attrs: { d: "M15.39,1c0.107" },
                children: nullm
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

is it possible to dynamically and on-the-fly create a nested "compiled" React element without babel within my React Native app's JS, like:

```
function el() {
  return React.createElement(
    Svg,
    { height: "40", width: "40", viewBox: "0 0 22 22" },
    React.createElement(
      G,
      null,
      React.createElement(
        Path,
        { d: "M15.39,1c0.107" }
      )
    )
  );
};
```

Comment: Why not creating a component that just renders the data structure?

Comment: Dunno. Maybe that's what I need to do? Perhaps I'm overthinking it? Can you give me some pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to do something like that ?

```
function createNodeElement(node) {
  return React.createElement(
    node.name,
    node.attrs,
    node.children && node.children.map(el => createNodeElement(el)),
  )
}
```

We can discuss more if the answer does not fulfill your needs.

Comment: Wow, this is even simpler than what I just came up with Just need to create the map of possible node types as per my example and do `types[node.name]`,

Answer (score 0):

@lumio corrected my course, and I needed to just render the js data structure. So with the following js:

```
const json = {
  type: 'Svg',
  props: {
    height: 170,
    viewBox: '0 0 100 170',
    width: 100,
  },
  children: [
    {
      type: 'Path',
      props: {
        d: 'M100 0H50v85l50-85z',
        fill: '#0f0',
      },
    },
    {
      type: 'Path',
      props: {
        d: 'M0 170h50V85L0 170z',
        fill: '#a0f',
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

And the following component:

```
const types = { Svg, Path };
const jsonToComponent = (obj, key) => {
  const El = types[obj.type];
  const children = obj.children ? obj.children.map(jsonToComponent) : [];

  return (
    <El
      key={key}
      {...obj.props}
    >
      {children}
    </El>
  );
};
```

I can render it within another dummy component:

```
render() {
  return jsonToComponent(props.json);
}
```